# Writing data to cell in existing excel through hssf/xssf.

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am in a dilemna. I have been trying to write data into an existing excel file through hssf/xssf in Java. I have no errors but still when I run it can't get change made to the excel sheet. Can anyone help me out with this? My code is:

```
try {
    FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Training/Desktop/saurav.xlsx");  


            Workbook wb = null;
            try {
                wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
            Row row = sheet.getRow(3);  
            Cell cell = row.getCell(4);  
            if (cell == null)  
                cell = row.createCell(4);  
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);  
            cell.setCellValue("a test");  

            // Write the output to a file  
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Training/Desktop/saurav.xlsx");  
            wb.write(fileOut);  
            fileOut.close();  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Someone please help me out with this.Trying this out since last 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of that use this, its working in my system.

```
try {
FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Training/Desktop/saurav.xlsx");  


        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
        Row row = sheet.getRow(3);  
        Cell cell = row.getCell(4);  
            cell = row.createCell(4);  
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);  
        cell.setCellValue("a test");  

        // Write the output to a file  
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Training/Desktop/saurav.xlsx");  
        wb.write(fileOut);  
        fileOut.close();  
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also make sure that you refresh the excel file after every run.